# duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize

Tags: duplicates

I'm getting this bug. Somebody help me.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _EstimateBas64DecodedDataSize in
    /Users/macmini04/Desktop/CB 14:10 7pm/CareerBuilder 12:10/Twitter+OAuth/
        SAOAuthTwitterEngine/libOAuth.a(Base64Transcoder.o) and
    /Users/macmini04/Desktop/CB 14:10 7pm/CareerBuilder 12:10/build/
        CareerBuilder.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CareerBuilder.build/
        Objects-normal/i386/Base64Transcoder.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
    failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have the same objct file `Base64Transcoder.o` listed explicitly on the command line and also within the `libOAuth.a` library.

In the hope that the fact they have *exactly* the same name means they're the same object file, you can probably just remove the explicit one and allow the one in the library to be used.

If they're *different* object files, then you need to investigate which will be best for your purposes. You can't normally have two object files with the same exported symbol.